# How can i use date_diff function with string values

Tags: php, string, date, strtotime

I have 2 string values like "24/10/2015" and "23/10/2015" and they are dynamic values. And i need the night count between this two values, so im trying to use date_diff but i couldn't manage it. I have tried strtotime, date_create_from_format etc. but it didn't work. Any advice?

Example code:

```
$checkout = $_COOKIE['cout'];
$checkin = $_COOKIE['cin'];
$nights = date_diff(strtotime($checkout),strtotime($checkin));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just create a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object with [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and then you can get the difference with [`diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php), like this:

```
<?php

    $dateOne = "24/10/2015";
    $dateTwo = "23/10/2015";

    $dateOne = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $dateOne);
    $dateTwo = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $dateTwo);
    $interval = $dateOne->diff($dateTwo);
    echo $interval->format("%d " . ($interval->d > 1 || $interval->d == 0?"nights":"night"));

?>
```

output:

```
1 night
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://viper-7.com/AixZOH)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution.

```
$checkout = $_COOKIE['cout'];
$checkin = $_COOKIE['cin'];
$datediff = strtotime($checkout) - strtotime($checkin);
$night = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $checkout = date_create("2015-10-12");
 $checkin = date_create("2015-10-05");
 $nights = date_diff($checkout,$checkin);

 print_r($nights);
```

You will get object array like this,

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 7
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 1
    [days] => 7
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```